Why do internal edges appear in MeshRegion?
why MeshRegion[] introduces additional (useless) edges in the construction of polyhedra:
surf=Dodecahedron[];
vlist=#&@@@MeshCells[surf,1];
Graphics3D[Line[MeshCoordinates[surf][[#]]]&/@vlist]


surf=MeshRegion[Dodecahedron[]];
vlist=#&@@@MeshCells[surf,1];
Graphics3D[Line[MeshCoordinates[surf][[#]]]&/@vlist]



MeshRegion is building a volume mesh filled with Tetrahedron. It's not just meshing the surface.

of course, you're right, I forgot the polyhedrons in Math are solids not surfaces, so the "useless" edges are just the edges of tetrahedrons coming form the volume triangulation.

We can use BoundaryMeshRegion
surf = BoundaryMeshRegion[Dodecahedron[]];


